# cygwin libxml2 outdated automake version

Tags: cygwin, version, libxml2, automake

I'm using Cygwin, and I am really impressed with the enhanced functionality of my Windows pc! However, I ran into a problem.

In order to setup Magento 2 on my Windows 8.1 Home pc, I need a virtual machine. Therefore I want to install libvirt, an open-source package that seems pretty old. However,on a Windows Home pc, it seems the only option. For libvirt to work, I need to setup an older version of libxml2: 2.6.0. Libvirt would not work with libxml2 2.7.0.

Installing libxml2 version 2.6.0 calls an old version of automake (1.6.3), which is unable to recognize my Windows file system.

I have tried changing aclocal.m4, replacing 'automake 1.6.3' to 'automake 1.15.1', but that didn't work:

```
AC_DEFUN([AM_AUTOMAKE_VERSION],[am__api_version="1.15.1"])

AC_DEFUN([AM_SET_CURRENT_AUTOMAKE_VERSION],
     [AM_AUTOMAKE_VERSION([1.15.1])])
```

Is there a way to install the old libxml2 version (2.6.0) using a new version of automake?

p.s.: I hope I made my issue clear. I apologize for newbee errors in my writing.

Comment: `automake 1.6` is available on cygwin and also `libxml++2.6-devel`

Comment: Thanks! 'apt-cyg install libxml++2.6-devel' works without any issues!